# converting a list to map in scala

Tags: scala

I am trying to convert a list to map in scala.

**Input**

```scala
val colNames = List("salary_new", "age_new", "loc_new")
```

**Output**

```scala
Map(salary_new -> salary, age_new -> age, loc_new -> loc)
```

Following code is working, but seems like I am over killing it.

```scala
 val colRenameMap = colNames.flatMap(colname => Map(colname -> colname.split("_")(0))).toMap
```

Comment: Well, you can change the `flatMap` with a `map` and remove the creation of the inner **Map**.

Comment: That worked. I was trying to do the same thing, but I had `Map` and it didn't worked. Not able to understand why?

Comment: `map` is defined like `def map[A, B](fa: F[A])(f: A => B): F[B]` _(F here is List, Map, Set, Vector, etc)_ so it takes a function and applies it to every element inside the collection. Whereas `def flatMap[A, B](fa: F[A])(f A => F[B]): F[B]` so it is like map, but it is aware of the intermediate collections and flatten them. So, if you lave the inner **Map** you construct a list of maps, which is not what you want.

Comment: I mean this one ` colNames.map(colname => Map(colname -> colname.split("_")(0)))`  I was not able to apply `toMap`  to this without using `flatMap`

Comment: Yes, it won't work. `toMap` transforms a list of tuples into a map, not a list of maps into a map. So, `list.map(Map)` returns a list of maps, `List.flatMap(Map)` returns a list of tuples and `list.map(Tuple)` also returns a list of tuples.

Answer (score 1):

I think `map` instead of `flatMap` would be more suitable for your case. Also you don't need to use the `Map` type internally, a single tuple should do the job.

For the sake of completeness this is how the definition of `toMap` looks like:

```scala
toMap[T, U](implicit ev: A <:< (T, U)): immutable.Map[T, U]
```

as you can see the method expects a `(T, U)` which is a `Tuple2`.

Finally, two options using `map`:

```scala
// option 1: key/value
colNames.map{c => c -> c.split("_")(0)}.toMap

// option 2: tuple
colNames.map{c => (c, c.split("_")(0))}.toMap
```